# How do I programmatically add a tableRow to TableLayout in Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin

So I have my layout that contains a TableLayout defined in my layout here

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@drawable/defaultBackground_vert"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:id="@+id/mainLayout">
<TableLayout
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/table">
</TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And I am accessing it in my codebehind and trying to add a button to a table row and add that tablerow to the table:

```
private TableLayout _table
private Button _button
.
.
.
_table = FindViewById<TableLayout>(Resource.Id.table);
_button = new Button(this){Text = "<"};
_button = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent);
var tableRow = new TableRow(this);
tableRow.AddView(_button, 0);
_table.AddView(tableRow, 0);
```

The problem is that the tableRow does not show up when I run my application.

Comment: @robert-watson did you ever get this fixed?

Answer (score 10):

You need to use TableRow.Layoutparams for the buttons.. Try this code.

```
    TableLayout _table = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.table);

    LayoutParams layoutParams = new TableRow.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(this);

    Button _button = new Button(this);
    _button.setText(">>");
    _button.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

    tableRow.addView(_button, 0);
    _table.addView(tableRow, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

I've refactored the code above, so that it would be in C# and not Java,
enjoy!

```
TableLayout _table = (TableLayout)FindViewById(Resource.Id.tableLayout1);

TableRow.LayoutParams layoutParams = new TableRow.LayoutParams(
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent,
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent);

TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(this);

Button _button1 = new Button(this);
_button1.Text = "1";
_button1.LayoutParameters = layoutParams;

Button _button2 = new Button(this);
_button2.Text = "2";
_button2.LayoutParameters = layoutParams;

Button _button3 = new Button(this);
_button3.Text = "3";
_button3.LayoutParameters = layoutParams;

tableRow.AddView(_button1, 0);
tableRow.AddView(_button2, 1);
tableRow.AddView(_button3, 2);

_table.AddView(tableRow, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

if you converted your code into xml it would be like

```
<TableRow><Button /></TableRow>
```

so you have to add layoutparams to each view you create programmatically

```
 _button = new Button(this){Text = "<"};
_buttonparams = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent);
_button.setLayoutParams(_buttonParams);
var tableRow = new TableRow(this);
LayoutParams _tableRowParams = new LayoutParams(-1,-2);
tableRow.setLayoutParam(_tableRowParams);
tableRow.AddView(_button, 0);
_table.AddView(tableRow, 0);
```